# How to rewrite url with post title slug?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Consider a url

```
www.example.com/paper-ads-details.php?req=43397&rnd=1308546000
```

I want to change this urls as:

```
www.example.com/jobs-in-chanai.php
```

where `req=43397` is pointing to the post titled as *jobs in chanai* 
How may i rewrite that? Please help me.

Comment: Why would you want `.php` in a friendly url? Besides that, you **really** want to include the page ID in the friendly url so you don't have to make your code less efficient (searching by the slug).

Comment: infect i want to hide the parameters and want to use the slug like wordpress.

Comment: Why not include both, e.g. 
`example.com/43397-jobs-in-chanai`

Comment: @Sohail You can use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) functionality, [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).. but RewriteMap directive cannot be declared in .htaccess file.

Comment: This question is [cross posted on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/q/283359/40193) by the same user under a different name with different details, just a little farther along in figuring out his issue. The OP marked it as solved there.

Comment: @caleb I got right answer there. Bundles of Thanks to StackExchange owner for giving this type of helpful platform. Thanks to all of you who considered my question to answer. rather strict but its Greate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hard time i got the way, and now sharing it for Other users...
Suppose the required Url is `www.example.com/programmer-Jobs-in-luton` 
 The Rule will be like...
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$  job-details.php?slug=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to use .htaccess, you need to write a script to generate the rewrite rules statically, so the .htaccess file contains lines like
   `RewriteRule ^jobs-in-chanai.php /paper-ads-details.php?req=43397&rnds=1308546000 [L]`
2. Handle the routing at the start of the request in PHP. Parse (and filter) the url to look up the post based on the slug rather than the req and rnds parameters. Cache the results if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your database you need a column for the 'clean url' or 'slug' as well as the .htaccess rules mentioned.

I use this function (not my code):

```
   function makeSlug($string, $force_lowercase = true, $anal = false) {
     $strip = array("~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]",
                   "}", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "\"", "'", "&#8216;", "&#8217;", "&#8220;", "&#8221;", "&#8211;", "&#8212;",
                   "â€”", "â€“", ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?");
    $clean = trim(str_replace($strip, "", strip_tags($string)));
    $clean = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $clean);
    $clean = ($anal) ? preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $clean) : $clean ;
    return ($force_lowercase) ?
        (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) ?
            mb_strtolower($clean, 'UTF-8') :
            strtolower($clean) :
        $clean;

}
```

I save this in a column and do something like :

```
"SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `clean_url` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($cleanURL) . "'";
```

Comment: slug is already available. how to adjust it in url using htaccess.

Comment: `$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);` would make sense to get rid of specialc characters like umlauts. Besides that, why do you have html entities in your makeSlug function? PHP doesn't parse them to characters..