# How to automatically get the slug even if the only supplied parameter is id using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo, slug

I want to get the slug even if only the id is supplied. For example I enter this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421212/
```

After the site has been loaded, the URL becomes:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421212/how-to-rewrite-url-with-post-title-slug
```

What I mean is that that I want to pull up the slug even if I only entered the Id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, you want to reproduce the stackoverflow url rewriting rules on your own apache/php env that's right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite does not know the right slug for the given ID. Your application that generates the slug does. So you grab the slug from the database using the ID and compare it with the one sent by the browser. If it does not match, issue a 301 redirect to the full (if slug was empty) or correct (if the slug did not match) URL. That's how SO works. Open these URLs and look at the net inspector to see what I mean:

- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393455/`
- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393455/foo-bar-blah-baz`

In PHP, inspect the `$_SERVER` super global, you should be able to find the variables that contain the actual URL before re-writing. And you can send `301` header like so:

```
header("Location: /1234/correct-slug", true, 301);
```

Comment: hmm.. this is interesting.. i'll try your recomendation

Answer (score 1):

In the page that loads, check for the slug almost immediately. If it doesn't exist, pull it out of the database (You have the ID) and redirect to the new full link.

If you do that before rendering any HTML etc, it'll look like it's been done without a redirect.

If you post your current htaccess, I can modify what you have to allow for both slug provided, and no slug provided.

Comment: Ohh I see I was thinking about that but I thought there might be a better way to do it, but if thats the case I'll try it now! Thanks bud!