# How to remove part of url in htaccess

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I want to have only last part of URLs in my blog using `.htaccess`.

```
https://example.com/blog/category1/category2/postname1
https://example.com/blog/category1/postname2
```

I want to have only:

```
https://example.com/blog/postname1
https://example.com/blog/postname2
```

Comment: That is not possible for obvious reasons: how should the rewriting engine know whether to rewrite to `category1/` or `category1/category2/` It cannot make up information from thin air...

Comment: @HastaDhana I am really new with htaccess I can just redirect simple ones

Comment: @arkascha Imagine I have maximum 2 categories and I want to remove cat1 in some posts and cat2 in others

Comment: The same as I already pointed out applies: how should the rewriting engine know what you eliminated in which case? Can _you_ tell me?

Comment: You could use RewriteMap and keep a lookup file up to date with all your posts and relevant categories.

Comment: @arkascha maybe number of slashes(/) in url... Is it possible?

Comment: No, that is not an option. You could use a slug that is a combination of category and post, concatenated by a "-" for example. That would be something that can be parsed. or some fixed substitution for the category so a final URL pattern like `/blog/1-2-postname1`.

Comment: To clarify, is `https://example.com/blog/postname1` currently a valid URL?

Comment: @MrWhite, No, I have hundres of urls I want to  remove categorizations from urls.

Comment: I mean, if you request a URL of the form `/blog/<postname>` (as opposed to `/blog/<category1>/<postname>`) does it work - does your application know how to route the request?

Answer (score -1):

User `RewriteRule` Rule 
The Rule will be like..

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$  blog/postname1?slug=$1 [L]
```

Check this url :- [How to rewrite url with post title slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421212/how-to-rewrite-url-with-post-title-slug)

Comment: Thank you very much. But There are many of urls. postname1 is just an example. Is it used for my thread?

Comment: Yes, try it. Did you use core PHP or other Framework?